# Cannot delete folder (which contains several other empty folders)

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7, and in my D drive is a folder I cannot delete, even though it says it is empty. Inside this folder are 26 also empty folders, 25 with 4 digit number names, like `1025` and `3082`, and one named graphics.

I am the sole user on this computer. when I try to delete it, it says i need admin permission to do so. I am the admin.

They are empty folders doing nothing, containing nothing, but it is driving me mad that I cannot delete it. Any idea?

Comment: You could start Windows in safe mode, and make sure no service is started that is using the folder. Then try to delete it.

Comment: What's the error message actually say?

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled?  That can cause funny things to happen, including problems like this, regardless of whether you are a local administrator or not.  Do you have the same problem if you try to delete using an elevated command prompt? (Click Start | type CMD | press Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: refer to [this similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/469430/cannot-delete-folder-content-seems-to-be-nested-recursively/) , it may help you too.

Answer (score 3):

Don’t worry about the suggestions to start in safe mode or using Process Explorer to look for open handles because that’s not what you are experiencing (if it were, you would be getting a *this file is open / locked* error, not a permission error).

What you need to do is to assign yourself permission (full-access) in the Security tab of the Properties dialog for the folder. Make sure to assign it to containing folders as well. You may also need to take ownership of the folder before being able to assign permission (in the Advanced section of the Security tab).

If you have difficulty doing this manually, you can install a [shell-extension](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) that makes it easier (but beware, it makes it easier for *all* files/folders).

For the record, those numbered folders are [localizations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040609-00/?p=38963) (each number represents a different language), containing files that localize the application for that language. The thing is, usually these folders are deletable my an administrator account unless they have been installed, so it sounds like you are trying to delete stuff from the Windows directory (which is usually a bad idea, and even if you do, they’ll probably be re-created anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether you have full control of that folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to find out if any process is still using one or more folders in that dir.. You can fire up Process Explorer and search by the path of the directory that you are trying to delete. If there are any processes with open handles to any of the files/dirs in that dir, it should show up. Kill those processes and then you should be able to delete the dir..

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the folder and click **Properties**, then go to the **Security** tab click **Advanced**. Go to the **Owner** tab and click **Edit**, then select the user you want to take ownership (your user) check the **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects** then click **OK**. Now as long and you have full control over that folder you should be able to delete it (or do whatever you want to with it).

Answer (score 0):

I'm suprised no one has mentioned this yet- you can generally bypass file system level security with another OS. Boot into a live cd, or some other means of running a linux system such as unetbootin or wubi. The NTFS 3g driver in that should be able to delete the folders in question.