# Access denied for another OS files

Tags: windows, blocking

I have dual boot windows 7 + 8. I really need to copy some data from users folder, etc... But when I open win 8 users folder in win 7 and I try to copy something, I get Access denied error. I'm accessing as admin. Please help me. I saw that Access error like thousands of times today :(

I already tried to change rights for that folder, got Access denied while changing...

Comment: did you use the admin user account from the win8 computer or win7? Otherwise use a Linux Live Cd: http://superuser.com/questions/450720/folder-cannot-be-deleted/450725#450725

Comment: There are some subtle differences in the way Windows 7 and Windows 8 process their NTFS. But a permissions **audit** should work, regardless of where it is made.

Comment: `E:\> takeown /?`

Comment: Windows will respect the ownership properties of other Windows installations.  This is the reason you cannot take a HDD out of `Computer A` and access all the data on it on `Computer B` unless of course you take ownership of the data.

Answer (score 0):

May be not the exact solution you want, but it might help in case you are on a hurry.
If you really need those files, you can boot [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) live and copy your data as you like

About ubuntu live [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Booting ubuntu as a live, it means You will not install it, you will just insert the usb/cd and boot from it, then ubuntu will open from there not from your hard disk. i.e. no installing/changing will be made to your pc at all.

Answer (score 0):

On the folder in question
1. Right click on it
2. Properties
3. Security
4. Advanced
5. Owner
6. Edit
7. Select either your local administrators group or your personal user name
8. Check the box that says "replace owner on subcontainers and objects
9. Click OK
10. Click OK
11. Click OK
12. Possibly watch a loading bar
13. Move files at your leisure.

Note: You may need to repeat this process on your Windows 8 install once you're all done moving stuff around. At this point, the folder you're accessing no longer belongs to your Windows 8 user account, so they're going to get the same access denied message you were getting.