# I can't delete a folder that's on my desktop, even after I've tried many different methods

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-permissions

> Could not find this item.
>
> This is no longer located in `C:\Users\(censored)\Desktop`. Verify the item's location and try again.

I have tried different solutions from people who have also had the same issue, but none of them have worked. Something to note: the folder has a space at the end.

Comment: there are several posts about this problem... http://superuser.com/questions/450720/folder-cannot-be-deleted/450725#450725 .... or .... http://superuser.com/questions/469683/i-cant-delete-a-file-even-when-using-unlocker/469698#469698

Comment: Unless you explain which methods you've used, it's hard for us to konw!

Comment: If the folder name contain dots, rename it to remove them, then delete normally. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to refresh the parent folder and/or reboot your computer?

If the folder is still there, you can boot good ol' ubuntu on a usb stick and remove the folder there.

Answer (score 0):

Try from CMD with RD . By dragging the folder to the command window, after typing RD, is the fastest.