# Cannot delete folder - Content seems to be nested recursively

Tags: windows

I cannot delete a folder located on my hard disk by any means.

I don't quite know how it was created, all I know is, that it is a pretty deep structure of folders (too deep to delete it at once, since Windows restriction path name too long), but the problem in the end is, that I can't "pull out" the inner folders, because they don't seem to be folders anymore (Context menu lacks things like "Properties", "Cut", "Copy", "Delete" etc.)

Here a picture of how a right click looks like on one of these "folders":

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the current folder is in very deep, but that is not the problem, rather the one I left-clicked on.

Has anyone any advice on how to get rid of these?

I tried a chkdsk, said no errors. I also tried deleting those folder via a VMWare Ubuntu, to no success. I also tried a batch file from a volunteer at MS boards, that should automatically de-nest such folders, but I guess mine is a special case, since the tool only created more such folders.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, I edited your post, if you don't like the changes feel free to edit it again or revert them.

Comment: Can you confirm that your menu when you right click (as pictured) only happens in these deep folders - if you right click on a folder on your desktop to you get the Copy/Cut/Property options?

Comment: @amotzg, Correct me if I'm wrong but, sfc looks and repairs an entirely different scope of things. ie. Not broken/chained/nested folders.

Comment: It seems you already have Ubuntu disc. Boot into Ubuntu Live CD and try deleting the folder from there. P.S.: Can you share the batch file you tried to use?

Comment: sfc stands for system file checker...it has nothing to do with other files/folders..

Comment: @DM8 remembered to hear about sfc solving problems as this one, hadn't the time to check it and thus didn't add an answer but a comment. Sorry for that. Deleted it.

Comment: Try using 7-zip, as outlined in this question. http://superuser.com/questions/78434/tool-for-deleting-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I tried it with the Live CD now too and it didn't work either (just moved them to a hidden folder named ".Trash.999", which wans't deletable itself then). @Dave Rook, Yes I can confirm that, the folder one level higher behaves like it should. I should also mention that when I click on the "bad" folder, nothing happens. I get the doubleclick sound but I am still in the same folder.

Comment: OK, I'm posting again to summarize how I got rid of them. First I deleted the original folder via Live Ubuntu (It worked though I thought it didn't, it could delete one of the two problematic folders, the other one being the one created by the batch script (BTW: <http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/cant-delete-folders-path-too-long-t283739.html>, Last post). Then i somehow managed in several attempts to delete the nested structure created by the batch via 7Zip. Thank you all for your help and i hope this is useful to someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe some files inside the folder (or deep inside the subfolders in it) are locked by Windows because they may be in use by other programs / processes.

When that happened to me, I used a program named "Unlocker" that, as its name implies, unlocks files in use and lets you delete them (and thus, delete the entire folder structure).

Note that Windows or your AV program may detect it as a virus, so use it at your own risk. Though, I've used it several times (at least back in the Windows XP days) and never had a problem.

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Another option is trying to delete the files/folders in Windows "safe mode" (hit F8 when rebooting your computer to enter that mode). You can even try "Unlocker" within safe mode and see what happens (I'm not sure).

And if those two options fail, then you may simply have a virus.

BTW, I doubt the folder "depth" itself is the cause of the problem, but more likely, the "effect" of having a virus.

Still, could you give us the full path here? It is suspicious that you have so many "Application Data" nested folders.